# Can anyone explain one step in the proof of the Lebesgue theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

> If the function f is monotone on the open interval (a, b), then it is
>   differentiable almost everywhere on (a, b).
>
> Proof： Assume f is increasing. Furthermore, assume (a, b) is bounded. Otherwise, express
>   (a, b) as the union of an ascending sequence of open, bounded intervals and use the
>   continuity of Lebesgue measure. The set of points x in (a, b) at which $\bar{D}f(x)$ > $\underline{D}$ f(x) is
>   the union of the sets
>   $E_{\alpha,\beta} = \{x\in E(a, b) \| \bar{D}f(x)>\alpha>\beta> Df(x)\}$
>   where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are rational numbers.

Why is the following true?  Should not $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real numbers?

> The set of points x in (a, b) at which $\bar{D}f(x)$ > $\underline{D}$
>   f(x) is the union of the sets $E_{\alpha,\beta} = \{x\in E(a, b) \|
> \bar{D}f(x)>\alpha>\beta> Df(x)\}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
>   rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are following Royden & Fitzpatrick's *Real Analysis*. First let me remind you a couple of definitions pertaining to your question:

Let $f:E\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function. Then

\begin{align}
\overline{D}f:&E^\circ\to\Bbb{R}& \underline{D}f:&E^\circ\to\Bbb{R}\\
&x\mapsto\limsup_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}& &x\mapsto\liminf_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
\end{align}

are the **upper** and **lower derivatives** of $f$ at $x$, respectively. Observe that $\forall x\in E^\circ: \overline{D}f(x)\geq\underline{D}f(x)$. $f$ is **differentiable** at $x\in E^\circ$ if $\infty>\overline{D}f(x)=\underline{D}f(x)>-\infty$, in which case

$$f'(x):=\overline{D}f(x)=\underline{D}f(x)$$

is the **derivative** of $f$ at $x$.

---

In Lebesgue's Theorem we are trying to show that the set $N$ where $f$ is not differentiable is negligible. By the definitions above, this set is precisely $N=\{\overline{D}f>\underline{D}f\}\subseteq E^\circ$. Even if $f$ is monotone, hence measurable, since the limit superior and inferior are not taken over a countable index we do not know yet that $N$ is measurable (hence we are using outer measure instead of the measure itself throughout).

Regardless, $\forall x\in N, \exists \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{Q}:\overline{D}f(x)>\alpha>\beta>\underline{D}f(x)$ by the density of $\Bbb{Q}$. This means we can write $N$ as a countable union of sets:

$$N=\bigcup_{\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{Q}\\\alpha>\beta}\{\overline{D}f>\alpha>\beta>\underline{D}f\}$$

and then we can employ the previous lemma (which is quite similar to Chebyshev's Inequality) on each one of them.

---

It is correct that

$$N=\bigcup_{\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{R}\\\alpha>\beta}\{\overline{D}f>\alpha>\beta>\underline{D}f\}$$

as well, but (outer) measure can handle at best countable operations, thus in order to turn $N$ into something managable we write it as a union of countably many sets.

---

As a final remark observe that we use a very similar procedure to show that the sum of two measurable functions is measurable (though this is not the only way to show this).